# ElastiCache - Redis Cluster mode enabled fails to write data in-between

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I am using a redis cluster of node type m5.4x large with 1 node , in-order to cache some results. The writes to this redis node is very frequent. And I could see that intermittently the writes to cluster fails.

Below is the stack trace we see in logs for the failure.

> org.redisson.client.WriteRedisConnectionException: Unable to send
>   command! Node source:
>   NodeSource[slot=null,addr=null,redisClient=null,redirect=null,entry=org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveEntry@6608962a],
>   connection: [id: 0xbad70cba, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:47904], command:
>   (EVAL),params: [local insertable = false; local value =
>   redis.call('hget',KEYS[1], ARGV[5]); local t, val;if value ..., 8,
>   SEARCH_CACHE, redisson__timeout__set:{SEARCH_CACHE},
>   redisson__idle__set:{SEARCH_CACHE},
>   redisson_map_cache_created:{SEARCH_CACHE},
>   redisson_map_cache_updated:{SEARCH_CACHE},
>   redisson__map_cache__last_access__set:{SEARCH_CACHE},
>   redisson_map_cache_removed:{SEARCH_CACHE},
>   {SEARCH_CACHE}:redisson_options, ...] at
>   org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService.checkWriteFuture(CommandAsyncService.java:675)
>   at
>   org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService.access$100(CommandAsyncService.java:84)
>   at
>   org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService$9$1.operationComplete(CommandAsyncService.java:638)
>   at
>   org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService$9$1.operationComplete(CommandAsyncService.java:635)
>   at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>   at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>   at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>   at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetFailure(AbstractChannel.java:987)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:869)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1371)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1081)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1128)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1070)
>   at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
>   at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown
>   Source)

I am using redisson client version 3.6.5. 
Can someone please help me to identify what is the issue?

Below is the configuration I have setup for redis cluster connection

- idleConnectionTimeout: 1000
- pingTimeout: 10000
- connectTimeout: 10000
- timeout: 30000
- retryAttempts: 3
- retryInterval: 1500
- reconnectionTimeout: 30000
- failedAttempts: 3
- subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
- slaveSubscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
- slaveSubscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 50
- slaveConnectionPoolSize: 250
- masterConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 5
- masterConnectionPoolSize: 250

Comment: _"writes to this redis node is very frequent"_ + _"intermittently the writes to cluster fails"_ Could just be an infrequent network blip or similar.  Have you designed any fallbacks for when connections fail (eg trying again etc)

Comment: hi Thank you for helping. Yes we have re-try mechanism for trying out 3 times.I will update the configurations of connection too in the question. Could you please help to figure out this ?